# How does the click on a label get transferred to its associated input?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an angular.js app, and for some exceedingly strange reason I cannot grasp, this works:

```
<div>
  <input id="foo" style="display:none" ng-click="ctrl.fnc()" />
  <label for="foo" style="button-like">Button</label>
</div>
```

But this does not:

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.fnc()">Button</button>
</div>
```

Now, I'm not terribly concerned with getting the latter working (even though it looks a lot better).  I'm more confused about what could be causing this.  MDN says "When a  is clicked or tapped, and it is associated with a form control, the resulting click event is also raised for the associated control."  To me, that means that the click event occurs on the input element but does not bubble from there, and then the original event continues bubbling.

However, clicking on the input does not run ctrl.fnc(), either by making the input visible or by running click() on it in the console.

As I said, I don't need a solution - and I don't have the time to try and search for a minimal example.  If someone can figure out what could cause angular to behave like this, that would be an interesting bonus, but mostly I just want to know how it's possible for a click on an input to behave differently than a click on its associated label.

Comment: <button ng-click="ctrl.fnc()">Button</button> works fine

Comment: Usually, yes.  There's something weird happening that, as mentioned, I don't understand.  As I can't provide a minimal example, I don't expect that anyone can tell me _why_ it's not working.  That's why I'm not asking about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In just basic HTML, a click event on a `<label>` is bubbled to its associated `<input>` linked with the `<input id="foo">` and `<label for="foo">`.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('hello'));
```

```html
<label for="foo">Label</label>
<input id="foo" />
```

That has nothing to do with Angular. It is a basic aspect of HTML and kind of a special case among elements. The click event will trigger both from clicking the input or the label.

In essence, `label.click()` calls its associated `input.click()`. This essentially creates two different events.

You can also see this with this which triggers for each parent element. If you click the label, you'll see both `label > form > div` as well as `input > form > div`.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('div'));
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('form'));
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('input'));
document.querySelector('label').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('label'));
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <label for="foo">Label</label>
    <input id="foo">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Unsurprisingly, this doesn't fix my problem, but it was what I wanted to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Got your question try playing around `id="foo"` and `for=foo` these two are linked via HTML relation.

hope this clears your confusion.

this is nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for the actual technical details.

Comment: for:

The id of a _labelable_ form-related element in the same document as the label element. The first such element in the document with an ID matching the value of the for attribute is the labeled control for this label element.
 
A label element can have both a for attribute and a contained control element, as long as the for attribute points to the contained control element.

Comment: I'm looking for how the event is handled.  I know how to link an input with a label.  Please read the whole question.

Comment: Please also note that I quoted the MDN myself, in the question.  MDN does not provide me with the details I'm looking for.